# manipulating space delimited text file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a text file in the following format

```
4 This is my test file 4500
5 This is test 6000
6 Not sure how it will work 9000

I want to extract data as follows

Field1 = 4
Field2 = This is my test file
Field3 = 4500
```

This is the first row, I want all rows in this format. Can anyone please help? I would like to do either sed or awk no perl. I would prefer sed and/or awk.

I'm having issues with the Field2 (which could be either single word or multiple words string) to enclose it with single or double quotes. rest I guess is easy. Please help

Comment: I couldn't really call this a proper space-delimited file since it doesn't distinguish spaces-as-delimiters from spaces-as-values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`...

```
sed -re 's/(\S+)\s+(.*)\s+(\S+)/Field1 = \1\nField2 = \2\nField3 = \3/g' file
```

Output:

```
Field1 = 4
Field2 = This is my test file
Field3 = 4500
Field1 = 5
Field2 = This is test
Field3 = 6000
Field1 = 6
Field2 = Not sure how it will work
Field3 = 9000
```

Comment: Will only work with some seds due to `\s` and `\n` and `-r` and will fail if "field 2" contains any digits.

Comment: Adding that `?` made it even less portable. If you get rid of that and anchor your final RE segment to the end of line I think it'll be better: `/^([0-9]+)\s+(.*)\s+([0-9]+)$`. You can even change the `[0-9]`s to `\S`s and then it's guaranteed to work in any locale AND it'll no longer care about whether those fields are digits or not: `/^(\S+)\s+(.*)\s+(\S+)$/`.

Comment: Looks good now, +1. Actually I see you didn't anchor the final RE segment and it still works so you don't need to anchor the first one either. All about symmetry.... :-).

Comment: When I tested both versions of awk and sed with real data, sed returned the data perfectly. Thank you all for your help. Im going with sed. Yaaaaaaaaaaa ho.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost always easy to come up with a "solution" that works for a given sample input set but much harder to come up with one that works period. Really think about your real-world possible input before selecting a "solution". This one may not produce the output you want if you have fewer than 3 fields in your input, if that's a possibility updated your sample input and expected output to show how you'd want that handled.

```
$ awk '{
         f2=$0
         gsub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"",f2)
         print "field1 =", $1
         print "field2 =", f2
         print "field3 =", $NF
}' file
field1 = 4
field2 = This is my test file
field3 = 4500
field1 = 5
field2 = This is test
field3 = 6000
field1 = 6
field2 = Not sure how it will work
field3 = 9000
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect but you can try using this `awk`:

```
awk '{s=$1;e=$NF; $1=$NF=""; gsub(/^ +| +$/, ""); 
            printf "f1=<%s>,f2=<%s>,f3=<%s>\n", s, $0, e}' file
f1=<4>,f2=<This is my test file>,f3=<4500>
f1=<5>,f2=<This is test>,f3=<6000>
f1=<6>,f2=<Not sure how it will work>,f3=<9000>
```

Comment: It works great. I just wanted to enclose the second field in quote so I could put pipe delimiter around it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: The only problem with this solution are that it will change any white space present within "field 2" so tabs or sequences of spaces will become single space chars for example.